# sqoop export from hive/hdfs to sybase IQ database

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, sap-iq

I am trying to export data from HDFS/HIVE to SYBASE IQ database, I have tried with almost all the tags possible to implement into my command and created temporary table with just 1 column.

Please find the command line below which I am using to export the table :

```
sqoop export --driver com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver --connect jdbc:sybase:Tds:xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/DATABASE=ABC --username user --password password --export-dir "hdfs directory to be exported" --table "target table name" --input-fields-terminated-by '\t' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n'.
```

EDIT:1)
Still no success... I have also tried changing the jdbc driver to a lower version(jconn3 from jconn4). Before this I have successfully exported my data to SQL server database and ORACLE database. The only error I am facing is "INPUT PARAMETER NOT SET, INDEX 0". I am really wondering now as am I the only person exporting data from hdfs to SYBASE IQ. Is there any other way of exporting the data other than sqoop?

It is becoming very crucial now. Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using using --batch --num-mappers X in your sqoop command.

Comment: Thanks Niral.... It worked...now i am able to export data to sybase IQ but unable to see data in sybase target table.

Comment: Try using jdbc3 driver (--driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver) along with delimiters in hexadecimal format ('\0x0a'). It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Place your jar i.e driver file in /usr/lib/sqoop/lib

Commands:

```
# check current dir
pwd 
# change path
cd /usr/lib/sqoop/bin

sudo sqoop export --connect jdbc:sybase:Tds:xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/DATABASE=ABC --username user --password password --table targettablename --export-dir "hdfs directory to be exported"
```

I hope it works.

Comment: The error i am getting in the logs is "input parameter not set, index 0".